# How i configure logrotate to not delete my log files after rotation?

Tags: linux, logging, unix, logrotate

There's a way to do this?

Comment: You should ask this question under serverfault.com.  This site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set a really large value for the `rotate` argument in the configuration section.

Even if you use a daily rotation, a value of `rotate 365000` would provide for a thousand years of saved logs -- and chances are you may have switched your OS by then.